# Use the laws of logic to prove $(p∧q) \Rightarrow p$ is a tautology.

Tags: logic

I have this problem on an assignment and I would like help with it:

> Use the laws of logic to prove $(p\land q) \Rightarrow  p$ is a tautology.

Thanks!

Comment: Hint: $((p\land q)\Rightarrow p) \iff (\neg(p\land q)\lor p)$

Comment: please share all need fast

Comment: What rules are you allowed to use?

Comment: Apply DeMorgan's Law, then use associations and commutivity.

Answer (score 3):

The only way $p \land q \Rightarrow p$ could be false, if the conclusion is false (so $p$ is false) but its assumption is true, and this cannot be, as $p$ is already false, so certainly $p\land q$ is. So it cannot be falsified, so it's always true.

Comment: Downvoted? I don't understand what was so incomprehensible about this simple explanation. I like it.

Comment: how to place DeMorgan law

Comment: What does de Morgan's law have to do with it? Are you instructed to use it? I'm not sure what deduction rules or definitions you are allowed to use. So I gave a simple semantic way.

Comment: i need solved equation

Comment: @ahmedsohail Did you read my comment about specifying which rules you can use? At least say what book you're using.

Comment: thaks got it. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

Semantically, you can consider an arbitrary truth-assignment $v$ s.t. $v(p \land q) = \top$. Can such an assignment make $p$ false? Hint:

> $v(p \land q) = \top$ iff $v(p) = \top$ and $v(q) = \top$.

Syntactically, as Graham pointed out, $((p \land q) \Rightarrow p) \equiv (\lnot(p \land q) \lor p)$, so if the formula is a tautology, its negation $\lnot(\lnot(p \land q) \lor p)$ should be a contradiction. Apply De Morgan's Laws and use the fact that $\land$ is associative. Solution:

> $\lnot(\lnot(p \land q) \lor p) \equiv ((p \land q) \land \lnot p) \equiv (p \land q \land \lnot p) \equiv (p \land \lnot p \land q) \equiv (p \land \lnot p) \land q \equiv \bot \land q \equiv \bot$

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are interested in [Propositional calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_calculus) here.

First we use Conjunction elimination:
$(p \land q) \vdash p$.

Now we use Conditional proof (conditional introduction):
$\emptyset \vdash (p \land q) \rightarrow p$.

Since $(p \land q) \rightarrow p$ is derivable from no assumptions, it must be a tautology.

Comment: Hunan, thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: No problem. Нет проблем ;)

Answer (score 1):

A formulaic approach: $$(p \land q \Rightarrow p ) \equiv  (p \lor \lnot(p \land q)) \equiv p \lor (\lnot p \lor \lnot q) \equiv (p \lor \lnot p) \lor \lnot q = \top \lor \lnot q \equiv \top$$

Which uses de Morgan's law, and other basic facts of Boolean algebra. I use that $a \Rightarrow b \equiv b \lor \lnot a)$

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to construct a truth table, then showing the statement $(p \land q) \Rightarrow p$ is a matter of showing all combinations of $p$ and $q$ are T/F. $(p \land q)$ is only true when both $p$ and $q$ are true. When both are true, then so is $p$, making your statement true, which takes care of $T \Rightarrow T$. The other three combinations have either $p$ or $q$ false, making $(p \land q)$ false. That gives the rest of the statements of the form $ F \Rightarrow \Box. $  Anything that follows from a false assumption is true, so the rest of the column is true regardless of what's in the box; making your statement a tautology.

Comment: need prove equation